# Aggregating daily data using quantmod 'to.weekly' function creates weekly data ending on Monday not Friday

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am trying to aggregate daily share price data (close only) to weekly share price data using the "to.weekly" function in quantmod. The xts object `foo` holds daily share price data for a stock starting from Monday 3 January 2011 and ending on Monday 20 September 2011. To aggregate this daily data I used:

`tmp <- to.weekly(foo)`

The above approach succeeds in that `tmp` now holds a series of weekly OHLC data points, as per the quantmod docs. The problem is that the series begins on Monday 3 January 2011 and each subsequent week also begins on Monday e.g. Monday 10 January, Monday 17 January and so on. I had expected the week to default to ending on Friday so that the weekly series started on Friday 7 January and ended on Friday 16 September.

I have experimented with adjusting the start and end of the data and using 'endof' or 'startof' together with the indexAt parameter but I cannot get it to return a week ending in Friday.

I am grateful for any insights received.
(Sorry, I could not find any way to attach dput file so data appears below)

foo:

```
2011-01-03 2802
2011-01-04 2841
2011-01-05 2883
2011-01-06 2948
2011-01-07 2993
2011-01-10 2993
2011-01-11 3000
2011-01-12 3000
2011-01-13 3025
2011-01-14 2970
2011-01-17 2954
2011-01-18 2976
2011-01-19 2992
2011-01-20 2966
2011-01-21 2940
2011-01-24 2969
2011-01-25 2996
2011-01-26 2982
2011-01-27 3035
2011-01-28 3075
2011-01-31 3020
```

tmp:

```
           foo.Open foo.High foo.Low foo.Close
2011-01-03     2802     2802    2802      2802
2011-01-10     2841     2993    2841      2993
2011-01-17     3000     3025    2954      2954
2011-01-24     2976     2992    2940      2969
2011-01-31     2996     3075    2982      3020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with something yielding only Close values, perhaps it can be hacked further to return OHLC series.

Assuming that `foo` is an `xts` object, first we create the vector of indeces of Fridays:

```
fridays = as.POSIXlt(time(foo))$wday == 5
```

Then we prepend it with `0`:

```
indx <- c(0, which(fridays))
```

And use `period.apply`:

```
period.apply(foo, INDEX=indx, FUN=last)
```

Result:

```
          [,1]
2011-01-07 2993
2011-01-14 2970
2011-01-21 2940
2011-01-28 3075
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoliy. I have adapted the code into a wrapper code and tested it with a few xts objects and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

For Fridays (with occasional Thursdays due to market closures), use:

```
tmp = to.weekly(foo, indexAt = "endof")
```

For Mondays (with occasional Tuesdays due to market closures), use:

```
tmp = to.weekly(foo, indexAt = "startof")`
```

Or you can create a custom vector of `Date`s that contains the date to be associated with each week.  For instance, to force every week to be associated with Friday regardless of market closures:

customIdx = seq(from = as.Date("2011-01-07"), by = 7, length.out = nrow(tmp))
   index(tmp) = customIdx